# How to change TSConfig lib for specific file or don't make lib types global

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, tsconfig, react-native-web

I'm using `react-native` and `react-native-web`, and have some code written using html DOM elements instead of react native components (`<div/>` instead of `<View/>`).

To properly type them I added `'DOM'` to `tsconfig.compilerOptions.lib`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "ES2021.String",
      "DOM" // <---
    ],
   ...
}
```

However I got a lot of global types that can ruin my code and lead to crash, for example `Image` can be used without importing from `react-native`:

```js
const SomeFC = () => {
    // no error here because Image type is global in DOM
    // but got crash in runtime
    return <Image />
}
```

I want to either override lib setting for specific files like this:

```js
// Here is the beginning for some file:
// @ts-config lib: ['DOM']
```

Or fing a way to remove DOM types from global and import them when necessary:

```js
import {Image, HTMLDivElement} from 'html-dom'
```

Or to at least pick global types that I need, or remove global types that I don't need.